# optimized query (count(*) as c) when 50m rows in table

Tags: sql, mariadb

How can this query be optimized? Because when im use SQL with limit and WHERE, hi work - fast. But when i try COUNT(*), sql execute 20sec. How can i get a better result? Suggest some articles please

[image: SQL Time]

Comment: show us the create table. and count is always bad in terms of performance, so it is the best to avoid it if possible, or in case if you really need it regurlarly, make a new table, which gets updated every time so you have at least a good approx of the count

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to user_to, if one doesn’t already exist.